# Handling dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown with some values :

- Apple
- Mango
- Orange
- Grapes

**HTML :**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="groupz">Role*</label>
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedRole" name="role" ng-change="GetRole(model.selectedRole)" >
      <option value class selected>Select Roles</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in model.roles track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I want my `$scope.selectedRole` to be by default as `Apple`. But later when the user needs to change the value, they can change it from apple to orange or any other fruit name. I have separate service request to fetch the fruits from backend and I write my code in controller as follows.

```
        $scope.GetRole = function() {

            $scope.selectedrole = [];
            if ($scope.model.selectedRole != null) {

                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    $scope.selectedrole.push($scope.model.selectedRole);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then assign the first array element to selectedrole containing the array of values(Apple Mango Orange Grapes)

Comment: Just assign the first element, you don't need to do a for loop for length 1.

Comment: question is unclear. Will you please elaborate

Comment: Hi , initially I need first value, later when user need to change. they must able to change the values.

Comment: Where is the object of dropdown elements. question is not clear please describe more.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitra/2s29neue/)

In js

```
 angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

 $scope.selectedrole  =  ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Grapes'];   
 $scope.selectRole= $scope.selectedrole[0];

  });
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<select ng-model="selectRole" ng-options="role for role in selectedrole">
 </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just try : HTML

```
<select class="form-control select" name="role" id="role" data-ng-model="ctrl.model.selectedRole" data-ng-options="option.name for option in ctrl.model.roles track by option.id"></select>
```

in your contoller

```
$scope.model = {
      roles: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'Apple'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Orange'
      }, {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Mango'
      }],
      selectedRole: {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Apple'
      } //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Then assign the first array element to selectedrole containing the array of values(Apple Mango Orange Grapes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default to be apple and the array is ordered:

```
array =  [Apple, Mango, Orange, Grapes]
```

Your model needs to be set to selectedRole:

```
data-ng-model="selectedRole"
```

In your controller, set:

```
selectedRole = array[0]
```

angular will take care of the rest of the data manipulation.

I hope this helps. Please provide more information for a clearer answer

Thanks

Comment: Hi , initially I need first value, later when user need to change. they must able to change the values.

Comment: Angular will take care of the data manipulation (angular will change the values later for you), please try the solution to see

Answer (score 0):

Handling a `select` element i.e. a drop down list in AngularJS is pretty simple.

Things you need to know is that you bind it to an array or a collection to generate the set of `option` tags using the `ng-options` or the `ng-repeat` directives which is bound to the data source on your `$scope` and you have a selected `option` which you need to retrieve as it is the one the user selects, it can be done using the `ng-model` directive.

If you want to set the selected `option` on the page load event, then you have to set the appropriate object or value (here it is the fruit id) which you are retrieving from data binding using the `as` clause in the `ng-options` directive as shown in the below embedded code snippet

```
ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in ctrl.fruits"
```

or set it to the value of the `value` attribute when using the `ng-repeat` directive on the `option` tag i.e. set `data.model` to the appropriate `option.value`

```
<select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
angular
  .module('fruits', [])
  .controller('FruitController', FruitController);
  
  function FruitController() {
    var vm = this;
    var fruitInfo = getFruits();
    vm.fruits = fruitInfo.fruits;
    vm.selectedFruitId = fruitInfo.selectedFruitId;
    vm.onFruitChanged = onFruitChanged;
    
    function getFruits() {
      // get fruits and selectedFruitId from api here
      var fruits = [
       { id: 1, name: 'Apple' },
       { id: 2, name: 'Mango' },
       { id: 3, name: 'Banana' },
       { id: 4, name: 'Orange' }
      ];
      
      var fruitInfo = {
       fruits: fruits,
        selectedFruitId: 1
      };
      
      return fruitInfo;
    }
    
    function onFruitChanged(fruitId) {
      // do something when fruit changes
      console.log(fruitId);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fruits">
  <div ng-controller="FruitController as ctrl">
    <select ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in ctrl.fruits" 
            ng-model="ctrl.selectedFruitId"
            ng-change="ctrl.onFruitChanged(ctrl.selectedFruitId)">
      <option value="">Select Fruit</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the Example section [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) for more information.